# Error handling for split-apply-combine strategy in Sparklyr

Tags: r, purrr, sparklyr

I have a Spark DataFrame with an ID column called "userid" that I am manipulating using `sparklyr`. Each `userid` can have anywhere from one row of data up to hundreds of rows of data. I am applying a function to each `userid` group which condenses the number of rows it contains based on certain event criteria. Something like

```
sdf %>%
  group_by(userid) %>%
  ... %>%   # using dplyr::filter and dplyr::mutate
  ungroup()
```

I would like to wrap this function in an error handler such as `purrr::possibly` so that computation will not be interrupted if an error occurs in a single group.

So far, I have had the most success using the [replyr](https://github.com/WinVector/replyr) package. Specifically, `replyr::gapply` "partitions from by values in grouping column, applies a generic transform to each group and then binds the groups back together."  There are two methods for partitioning the data: "group_by" and "extract".  The authors only recommend using "extract" in the case that the number of groups is 100 or less, but the "group_by" method does not work as I'd expect:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr) 
library(replyr)   # replyr::gapply
library(purrr)    # purrr::possibly

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

# Create a test data frame to use gapply on.
test_spark <- tibble(
  userid = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  occurred_at = seq(1, 6)
) %>%
  sdf_copy_to(sc, ., "test_spark")

# Create a data frame that purrr::possibly should return in case of error.
default_spark <- tibble(userid = -1, max = -1, min = -1) %>%
  sdf_copy_to(sc, ., "default_spark")

#####################################################
# Method 1: gapply with partitionMethod = "group_by".
#####################################################

# Create a function which may throw an error. The group column, userid, is not 
# included since gapply( , partitionMethod = "group_by") creates it.
# - A print statement is included to show that when gapply uses "group_by", the 
# function is only called once.

fun_for_groups <- function(sdf) {
  temp <- sample(c(1,2), 1)
  print(temp)
  if (temp == 2) {
    log("a")
  } else {
    sdf %>%
      summarise(max = max(occurred_at),
                min = min(occurred_at))
  }
}

# Wrap the risk function to try and handle the error gracefully.

safe_for_groups <- purrr::possibly(fun_for_groups, otherwise = default_spark)

# Apply the safe function to each userid using gapply and "group_by".
# - The result is either a) only the default_spark data frame.
#                        b) the result expected if no error occurs in fun_for_groups.
#   I would expect the answer to have a mixture of default_spark rows and correct rows.

replyr::gapply(
  test_spark, 
  gcolumn = "userid", 
  f = safe_for_groups, 
  partitionMethod = "group_by"
)

#####################################################
# Method 2: gapply with partitionMethod = "extract".
#####################################################

# Create a function which may throw an error. The group column, userid, is 
# included since gapply( , partiionMethod = "extract") doesn't create it.
# - Include a print statement to show that when gapply uses partitionMethod 
#   "split", the function is called for each userid.

fun_for_extract <- function(df) {
  temp <- sample(c(1,2), 1)
  print(temp)
  if (temp == 2) {
    log("a")
  } else {
    df %>%
      summarise(max = max(occurred_at), 
                min = min(occurred_at),
                userid = min(userid))
  }
}

safe_for_extract <- purrr::possibly(fun_for_extract, otherwise = default_spark)

# Apply that function to each userid using gapply and "split".
# - The result dataframe has a mixture of "otherwise" rows and correct rows.

replyr::gapply(
  test_spark, 
  gcolumn = "userid", 
  f = safe_for_extract, 
  partitionMethod = "extract"
)
```

How bad of an idea is it to use `gapply` when the grouping column has millions of values?  Is there an alternative to the error handling strategies presented above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replyr::gapply()` is just a thin wrapper on top of `dplyr` (and in this case `sparklyr`).

For the grouped mode- the result can only be correct if no group errors out, as the calculation is issued all at once.  This is the most efficient mode, but can't really achieve any sort of error handling.

For the extract mode- it might be possible to add error handling, but the current code does not have it.

As the `replyr` author I would actually suggest looking into `sparklyr`'s [`spark_apply()`](https://spark.rstudio.com/reference/spark_apply/) method.  `replyr`'s gapply was designed when `spark_apply()` was not available in `sparklyr` (and also when binding lists of data was also not available in `sparklyr`).

Also [`replyr` is mostly in "maintenance mode"](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=replyr) (patching issues for clients who used it in larger projects), and probably not a good choice for new projects.

Comment: Great, thank you for the feedback.  I'll look into using `spark_apply()` for the error handling piece.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the `gapply` code defaults to restricting the maximum group size to 100 for the extract and split modes?  I noticed in the source code that those two methods rely on `lapply`.

Comment: `gapply` defaults to no more than 100 groups (not group size of 100). This is because the re-join tends to be expensive as the number of groups goes up and I wanted to catch cases where the user didn't really have a large number of groups, but accidentally looked like they did due to key misspecification.

Comment: Gotcha. I was going to ask if using something `replyr_split`, `lapply`, and `sdf_bind_rows` would provide faster results, but I see that `gapply` is effectively the same since it calls `replyr_bind_rows` which calls `sdf_bind_rows` if possible (https://github.com/WinVector/replyr/blob/master/R/bind_rows.R#L66).